# How does the expr command work?

Tags: tcl

```
puts "-1/2 is [expr -1/2]"
```

For the above, the output is:

```
-1/2 is -1
```

I don't know how it's working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `-1/2`, you are passing the division of two integers to the interpreter and hence are telling it to do an integer division, which returns the closest integer, smaller than the result otherwise.

For instance, -1/2 gives -0.5, and -1 is the closest integer below -0.5.

Some other examples:

```
% expr 5/2    ;# Should give 2.5, closest integer down is 2
2
% expr -5/2   ;# Should give -2.5, closest integer down is -3
-3
% expr 5/-2   ;# Should give -2.5, closest integer down is -3
-3
```

If you want to get -0.5 as result, you can either change one of the two values to be a float number...

```
% expr -1.0/2
-0.5
% expr -1/2.0
-0.5
```

Or use `double` on either number

```
% expr double(-1)/2
-0.5
% expr -1/double(2)
-0.5
```

Note that for better speed and prevention of injection, you might want to [brace your `expr`essions](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225)

Comment: No need to brace when using very simple expressions like these, but as soon as the expression contains a complex literal, or a variable, or a command substitution, it should be braced. Which is almost all _real_ expressions…